# How to put .db file from assets to data/data/packagename/ android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application)

how to put .db file from assets to data/data/packagename/ without using copying content of .db file in assets. I don't want to create database because its useless to put the .db file in assets. I explore on it but all are again creating databse but i only want to put that .db file directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName =  "/data/data/"
            +getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/databases/" + DB_NAME;
    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

    }
    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

Comment: i don't want to use that. i simply want to copy .db file in data/data/packagename

Comment: That's what this is doing.  There's no "copy" function available to invoke, so the program must actually write out a new file itself.  The original is read-only so can't be "moved".  And there is no way to package a writable copy in the .apk.

Comment: that is the only way to put db from asset... otherwise you have to make a database programetically..

Comment: this gives me filenotfound exception in that directory. there is no folder named databases,