# Compiling app with web data included for offline use

Tags: android, webview, offline

I wonder if it's possible to compile an android app with web data already included in apk for offline use. Application downloads data (HTML), saves on device(HTML and images separately) and displays it in webview, but I wonder if it's possible to compile this app with all data and pictures already in device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I store all the data in database all I have to do is go through all the categories I want be available offline at app install, store the db file in /assets/ folder and then once user launches the app for the first time use copy method from here [How to put .db file from assets to data/data/packagename/ android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379433/how-to-put-db-file-from-assets-to-data-data-packagename-android) and I'm all set. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.mWebView);

            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///book.html");
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
{ 
    @Override 
    //show the web page in webview but not in web browser
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
        view.loadUrl (url); 
        return true;
    }
}
```

For More information

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-webview-loading-custom-html-and.html

Comment: I think he want load data from html file already downloaded in his files(apk) , custom html if he want control his webview